# VS Code assist for Python create new method if they not exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, code-completion, code-assist

I am new to VS code and Python :). I am trying :)

Java is my main coding language and I use(love) IntelliJ IDEA for coding. I chose VS code for python(for many reasons I cannot control)

In InteliJ when coding java , InteliJ code assist prompt for creation of new methods if they not exists, I found this very useful( check attached image)
[image]

I couldn't find equivalence in VS code for python, Is there is any extension I can use to get this behaviour and many other InteliJ assists( eg: suggestions)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Two suggestions that might help:

**1. [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) extension**

After installation, add configuration in `settings.json` according to the format.

*E.g:*

```json
  "my-code-actions.actions": {
    "[python]": {
      "import {{diag:$1}}": {
        "diagnostics": ["\"(.*?)\" is not defined"],
        "text": "import {{diag:$1}}\n",
        "where": "afterLast",
        "insertFind": "^(import |from \\w+ import )"
      }
    }
  }
```

*Effect:*

[image]

[image]

**2. Custom code snippets**

open in sequence **File** > **Preferences** > **Configure User Snippets**. Select **python** in the command palette. This will create a `python.json` file in which you can customize the code segment according to the rules.

*E.g:*

```json
    "Print to console":{
        "prefix": "defHello",
        "body": [
            "def Hello():",
            "${1:    }print('Hello worle')",
            "$2",
        ],
        "description": "print hello world"
    }
```

*Effect:*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have to look elsewhere , I settled with **PyCharm** which is developed by InteliJ folks